# Android Dialog title color and title button?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, styles

I have a button that when clicked it opens a dialog with information from my SQLite database. I have figured out how to change the background color and the color of the text but I am having trouble getting the title text color set.  Also I was wondering if at all possible is there a way to put a button in one of the corners of the title of a Dialog? I would like to have the close button positioned there.

Here is the code from my onClickHelp button which sets the dialog

```
public void onClickHelp(View v) {
    final Dialog duDialog = new Dialog(this);
    duDialog.setContentView(R.layout.data_usage);
    duDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.title_text);

    duDialog.setTitle("Data Usage"); // I would like to set the color and add button here
    ListView data = (ListView) duDialog.findViewById(R.id.DataUsage);
    duCursor = Data.getAll(db);
    startManagingCursor(duCursor);
    duAdapter = new DataAdapter(duCursor);
    data.setAdapter(duAdapter);
    duDialog.show();

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must design your own custom alert dailog with with your relevent design.

Refer this links

[LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) document for dialog

[LINK](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application) sample for customizing alert dialogs